# How to properly read binary encodings from a text file in Rust?

Tags: rust, utf-8, serde

I have a YAML file with test cases for encoding and decoding elements. The left-hand side represents the expected encoded bytes, and the right-hand side contains the original element. For example, the VarInt test cases are:

```
examples:
"\0": 0
"\u0001": 1
"\u000A": 10
"\u00c8\u0001": 200
"\u00e8\u0007": 1000
"\u00a9\u0046": 9001
"\u00ff\u00ff\u00ff\u00ff\u00ff\u00ff\u00ff\u00ff\u00ff\u0001": -1
```

The encodings (left-hand side) for the first three examples work correctly when read as strings (which are automatically interpreted as UTF-8 in Rust).

However, the fourth example (200) and the subsequent ones don't yield the correct results. Using the encoding for 200 ("\u00c8\u0001") as an example:

Reading the encoding as a UTF-8 string (incorrect):

```
use bytes::{Buf, BufMut};

let encoding_as_utf8_string = "\u{00c8}\u{0001}";
// "È\u{1}"
println!("Encoding as a UTF-8 string: {:?}", encoding_as_utf8_string);

let mut utf8_bytes: &[u8] = encoding_as_utf8_string.as_bytes();
// [195, 136, 1] (Incorrect)
println!("Bytes obtained from the encoding when read as a UTF-8 string: {:?}", utf8_bytes);
```

Reading the encoding as a byte array (correct):

```
use bytes::{Buf, BufMut};

let string_from_byte_array: String;
unsafe {
    let encoding_as_byte_array: &[u8; 2] = b"\xc8\x01";
    string_from_byte_array = String::from_utf8_unchecked(encoding_as_byte_array.to_vec());
}

// "�"
println!("Encoding string read from byte array: {:?}", string_from_byte_array);

let mut bytes: &[u8] = string_from_byte_array.as_bytes();
// [200, 1] (correct)
println!("Bytes obtained from the encoding when read as a byte array: {:?}", bytes);
```

The issue here is that when reading from the YAML file, the encodings (Mapping keys) get automatically interpreted as UTF-8 strings, so the original bytes are lost:

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_yaml::{Deserializer, Value};

let f = std::fs::read(yaml_dir).expect("Unable to read file");
    
for doc in Deserializer::from_slice(&f) {
    let spec = Value::deserialize(doc).expect("Unable to parse document");

    // Mapping {..., "examples": Mapping {"\0": Number(0), "\u{1}": Number(1), "\n": Number(10), "È\u{1}": Number(200), "è\u{7}": Number(1000), "©F": Number(9001), "ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ\u{1}": Number(-1)}}
    println!("YAML spec interpreted: {:?}", spec);
}
```

A more specific example using serde_yaml:

```
// Sequence [Number(200), Number(1)] (Correct, but how to make the YAML get interpreted like this?)
let bytes = serde_yaml::to_value(b"\xc8\x01").unwrap();

// String("È\u{1}") (Incorrect)
let st = serde_yaml::to_value("\u{00c8}\u{0001}").unwrap();
```

I'm using serde_yaml but any other approach would be acceptable. How can I make it so that the encodings in the YAML, exactly as they are written, are correctly interpreted as byte arrays instead of strings?

I know serde_yaml has methods such as [deserialize_bytes](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/latest/serde_yaml/enum.Value.html#method.deserialize_bytes-1), but I'm not sure how to apply them in this case.

Alternatively, is there a way to continue reading the encodings normally as UTF-8 strings and then extract the original non-UTF-8 bytes from them?

Comment: Note that having strings that represent non utf-8 valid strings is UB. Which suggests that maybe what you want is `Vec<u8>`, not `String`?

Comment: You're right. Unsafe behavior would be acceptable for this use case, but obtaining a Vec<u8> would be better.

Comment: `È\u{1}` is correct, that's `\u00c8\u0001`. If you want to represent a number using unicode codepoints, you have to write a parser yourself, I do not understand the expectancy for the parser to convert it for you. `[195, 136, 1] (Incorrect)` that's correct utf-8 for `È\u1`. You want utf-32? that's not bytes, that's words.

Comment: @NivaldoT UB is never acceptable. Maybe you don't exactly know what it means (in Rust): if you ever reach UB, it means the compiler makes no promises about what might happen. It doesn't mean "now, if you make a call to an other function, there might be a problem because", it means "Rust has to right to have produced code that instantly blows up your computer". It's likely not what will happen in this case, but it is *never* a good thing to reach UB.

Comment: @jthulhu Is there a way to get `serde_yaml` to interpret map keys as anything but `String`? I've tried `bstr` and even a custom deserializer, and I can't see a way of getting around `examples: invalid type: string \"\\0\", expected a sequence`.

Comment: Rel: [How to encode a VarInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74963506/how-to-properly-encode-a-varint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u00c8` is UTF-16 for character `È`. That's not 200. That's character `È`. You have written character `È`. Not 200.

`195, 136` or `0xC3 0x88` is UTF-8 for character `È`. This is how character `È` is represented as bytes in Rust.

If you want to print UTF-16 of a character, you want to print `u16`, not `u8`. Try:

```
fn main() {
    let st = serde_yaml::to_value("\u{00c8}\u{0001}").unwrap();
    let v: Vec<u16> = st.as_str().unwrap().encode_utf16().collect();
    println!("{} {}", v[0], v[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A superficial reading of `serde_yaml`'s [code](https://github.com/dtolnay/serde-yaml/blob/aed75edf521f203ad6b57a7fd93f89b4bc70203c/src/de.rs#L858) suggests that it will always try to convert your YAML string keys to `str` (which must fail since they're not valid utf8) and you can't get a `[u8]` out of them. I suggest you change your YAML:

```yaml
examples:
  [0]: 0
  [0x01]: 1
  [0x0A]: 10
  [0xc8, 0x01]: 200
  [0xe8, 0x07]: 1000
  [0xa9, 0x46]: 9001
  [0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x01]: -1
```

This [can be parsed by `serde_yaml`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74b8e6dde10d558d9c63740e9012cf62), but alas, you said you don't want to do that.